# Embedding into $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, jacobian

I am trying to find a map that goes from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^6$ such that it is an embedding. Im trying to use the fact that $S^2$ is compact and that I can find a map $\psi$ that is an injective immersion which would then make $\psi$ an embedding. Thinking about the Monge parametrization for the sphere i would get:

$$ \psi(x,y,z) = (x,y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},0,0,0) $$

whose Jacobian matrix is:

$$  J(x,y,z) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0\\
 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}   \\
 0  & 0  \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  
\end{array}\right) $$

but this only covers the top hemisphere, I could do a composition with the negative root but I find it problematic. For instance I can't justify that the rank of the Jacobian is $3$ so I couldn't say its an immersion. Is there an injective immersion from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^6$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the question. The standard realization of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding. Adding three extra dimension does not make it any less of an embedding.

Comment: How do I prove that $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding? Using the spherical coordinates parametrization of the sphere the Jacobian matrix should always have rank $3$ right? (in order for it to be an immersion)

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh I hope you meant rank 2. A matrix with only two columns can't have rank 3.

Comment: the number 6 suggests the Veronese embedding.

Comment: But if we choose $\theta =0$ and $\phi=0$ it will have rank 1, right? It must always have rank $=2$ in order to be an immersion, right?

Comment: @WillJagy But the Veronese map embeds $\Bbb RP^2$ in $\Bbb RP^5$?

Comment: @Ted, right. What I had in mind is the unit sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$  and map $(x^2, y^2, z^2, yz, zx, xy)$ that is two to one, as intermediate step before making projective. Also, there had been a few questions (in the past week or two) on exactly the map I write here.

Comment: Yes, @WillJagy, there sure have been. We're getting all sorts of exam questions with high multiplicity.